# curl request Receiving 403 Forbidden

Tags: curl, proxy

I'm sending a curl request via a proxy server and getting "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" in the output. 
How can I resolve this issue?

```
[root@  ~]# curl -x $http_proxy -ILk www.google.com
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: squid/3.5.20
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2020 13:57:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3577
X-Squid-Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0
Vary: Accept-Language
Content-Language: en
```